# How to extract (in C#) a specific attribute from every element of a List, and get a new List of these attributes?

Tags: c#, list

We begin with a `List<X>`.  Every object of X has an attribute x of type Y.  Could you propose an elegant way to construct a List which is composed of the `Z.x` for every element Z of some `List<X>`?
I'm sure "manual" iteration over `List<X>` isn't necessary.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 10):

If this is `List<T>`, then:

```
var newList = oldList.ConvertAll(item => item.x);
```

or with LINQ:

```
var newList = oldList.Select(item => item.x).ToList();
```

Note that in C# 2.0 the first version might need the generic type mentioned explicitly:

```
List<Y> newList = oldList.ConvertAll<Y>(delegate (X item) { return item.x; });
```

(but that is actually 100% identical to the first line)

There is also a static `Array.ConvertAll` which behaves similarly, but for arrays.